# How to set the factor in disaggregate function

Tags: r, pixel, resolution, raster

I have a question regarding the aggregation of rasters/pixels. 
I have a rasterstack with spatial resolution of `25km x 25km` and I want to change it to `500m x 500m` and preserve its values.
I believe that I must use the `disaggregate` function but I do not understand from the help page how to set the factor.

Comment: It is, I believe, well explained on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278825/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-raster-layer-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the resolution of a raster layer in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278825/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-raster-layer-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to go from 25 km to 500 m resolution. In that case, the factor is `25000 / 500 = 50`

If you want to change the resolution with a factor that is not an integer, you can use `resample` instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The suggested similar question by Lokinou and divibisan does not make clear what happens in cases where the factor is a decimal number. E.g. if someone wants to change from 250m x 250m to 550m x 550m should he/she set the factor to 2, 3 or 2.2? Thanks.

Comment: In that case you can use `resample`