# Interpolate gridded climate data to different resolutions in R

Tags: r, interpolation, raster

I have raster data with a resolution of 0.5 degrees. I would like to
interpolate these to 0.125 and to 1 degree using nearest neighbour interpolation

How can this be implemented in R? Below is some example data:

```
library(raster)
ras <- raster(res=0.5)
#get polygons for Iceland
iceland <- getData('GADM', country="Iceland", level=1)
cr <- crop(ras, iceland, snap="out")
values(cr) <- 1:ncell(cr)
fr <- mask(cr, iceland)

plot(fr)
lines(iceland)
```

Comment: This should get you there as addresses both up and down resolution [raster::aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278825/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-raster-layer-in-r), with a number of approaches and raster nuance wrinkles, HTH

Comment: please make a reproducible by including some example data (not a file; unless it ships with R)l you can use `raster()`. and please use a small area. Use Iceland, not Canada.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you, Robert. Done!

Comment: Thanks. The resolution is 0.5 degrees. What do you want it to be?

Comment: @RobertHijmans 0.125 degree and 1 degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
ras <- raster(res=0.5)
#get polygons for Iceland
iceland <- getData('GADM', country="Iceland", level=1)
cr <- crop(ras, iceland, snap="out")
values(cr) <- 1:ncell(cr)
fr <- mask(cr, iceland)
```

1 degree

```
a <- aggregate(fr, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

0.125 degree

```
d <- disaggregate(fr, 4)
```

Dis-aggregating data like that may be practical, but it may not be appropriate. It obviously is not a good way to change the resolution of climate data (but you asked *how* to do it, and that is what this site is for)

If the new resolution cannot be obtained by multiplying or dividing with an integer, there is `resample`

```
target <- raster(fr)
res(target) <- 1/13
r <- resample(fr, target, "ngb")

#or alternatively
rb <- resample(fr, target, "bilinear")
```